# I need this in years not days, the year should be 3 or 7 or 15, how would I write this in sharepoint calculation?

Tags: date, sharepoint, calculation

Here's what I have in days.

=IF(DRS="1.1.01",[Cut Off Date]+1050,IF(DRS="1.4.15",[Cut Off Date]+2500,IF(DRS="3.1.05",[Cut Off Date]+5380)))

I tried what I saw on the internet, where I put DATE(YEAR([Cut Off Date] etc. etc. but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it by days

```
=IF(DRS="1.1.01", [Cut Off Date] + 3*365, 
 IF(DRS="1.4.15", [Cut Off Date] + 7*365, 
 IF(DRS="3.1.05", [Cut Off Date] + 15*365, 0)))
```

or add it by years

```
=IF(DRS="1.1.01", DATE(YEAR([Cut Off Date]) + 3, MONTH([Cut Off Date]), DAY([Cut Off Date])),
 IF(DRS="1.4.15", DATE(YEAR([Cut Off Date]) + 7, MONTH([Cut Off Date]), DAY([Cut Off Date])),
 IF(DRS="3.1.05", DATE(YEAR([Cut Off Date]) + 15, MONTH([Cut Off Date]), DAY([Cut Off Date])),
 [Cut Off Date])))
```

Comment: Here's another quandry, I used the second option, years, but only the first statment works, if I put more than that statement, it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, it totally worked!  Thanks so much!